# Difference diagonals

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I tried to make this function that receives an array with N rows and N columns where it is summed the values of the main diagonal and the values of the secondary diagonal and at the end, the function calculates the difference of these numbers. However, when calculating the secondary diagonal, when calculating, for example, in a 3x3 array the position [1][1], it does not sum, as if the function ignored the business rule that was imposed on else if.

My code

```
function diagonalDifference (arr){
    let n = arr.length;
    let diagonPrim = 0;
    let diagonSec = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (i == j){
                diagonPrim += arr[i][j];
                console.log(i, j);
                console.log(diagonPrim);
            } else if (i == j || i + j == n - 1){
                diagonSec += arr[i][j];
                console.log(i, j);
                console.log(diagonSec);
            };
        };
    };
    let sum = diagonPrim - diagonSec;
    return sum;
}
```

Obs. I put the consoles.log the if's to know if I was jumping the positions in the array.

Example:

Input:

```
10, 2, 3,
4, 52, 6,
11, 8, 52,
```

Output expected:

48

My output :

100

Could you help me figure out why this one position doesn't calculate?

Comment: Could we see some input with expected output? It's also not entirely clear what a "primary" and "secondary" diagonal is.

Comment: Why is the `i == j` check duplicated in `else if`? Just an oversight or were you expecting `diagonSec` to also update if that is the case?

Comment: i tried to do without checking `else if `no else if though it was failed the same way

Comment: A more efficient solution would be to loop directly on the main and secondary diagonals. Note that the main diagonal (top left -> bottom right) consists of elements `arr[i][i]` and the secondary (top right -> bottom left) consists of `arr[n - 1 - i][i]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have an `if-else` statement. If the first condition executes, the second will not, even if its condition is true. Thus, the middle element will be counted only for the primary, not the secondary, diagonal.

In addition, you have an unnecessary condition (`i == j`) in your secondary diagonal check, as chazsolo comments. `i + j === n - 1` is a sufficient condition for checking the secondary diagonal.

Try like this instead:

```
function diagonalDifference (arr){
    let n = arr.length;
    let diagonPrim = 0;
    let diagonSec = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (i === j){
                diagonPrim += arr[i][j];
            }
            if (i + j === n - 1){
                diagonSec += arr[i][j];
            };
        };
    };
    let sum = diagonPrim - diagonSec;
    return sum;
}
```

EDIT: However, even if correct, this is still not an efficient way to solve this problem. If performance is important, you can solve the problem by looping directly over the diagonals without having to check all *n<sup>2</sup>* elements, see wLui155's comment.

Comment: @GustavoMegazorde You're welcome :) Notice however also wLui155's comment: My answer only contained the fix for your code, but it is still not the best way to solve this problem. If performance is important for you, it is better to loop along the diagonals directly, without having to check all *n^2* elements. Even for quite small matrices, the difference would be noticeable since it's *O(n)* vs *O(n^2)*.